# How to get filename from url considering all cases?

Tags: c#, http, filenames, content-disposition

I want to get the filename from a url working without any exception but I don't know all possible cases. I have the method below but it doesn't work for all cases. If anyone did this before please help

```
public static string getFileName(HttpWebResponse response, string requestUrl)
{
    var cd = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
    var loc = response.Headers["Location"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cd))
    {
        var disp = new ContentDisposition(cd);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1254).GetBytes(disp.FileName));
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loc))
        return Path.GetFileName(loc);
    else
        return Path.GetFileName(response.ResponseUri.OriginalString);
}
```

**UPDATE**: example cases added

**Case example 1:**

```
http://www.example.com/some/path/to/a/file.xml?foo=bar#test
filename = file.xml
```

**Case example 2:**

```
http://www.example.com/some/path/to/a/watch?filename=file.xml&foo=bar
filename = file.xml
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work for all cases". Mention a case, the output you get and the output you expect. Not all URLs have filenames in them, and not all endpoints return a content-disposition header with a filename. Browsers also do some magic to determine the filename, for example simply using the last **path** part of the URI, appending a default extension for the given mime type.

Comment: Youir examples aren't exhaustive. What if there's an URL like `https://example.com/download?id=5`? There's no filename in there, and definitely not a unique one if you need that. Do you know the format of all URLs that will pass this code? Otherwise you're going to have to generalize. One way would be to look at the content-type response header and the path of the URI, and determine a filename from that, like `download.xml` when the content-type indicates an XML response

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution myself and it seems working for all cases (at least for the cases I thought).

```
public static class FileNameHelper
{
    public static string GetFileName(HttpWebResponse resp)
    {
        var cdHeader = resp.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
        var location = resp.Headers["Location"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cdHeader))
        {
            var pattern = string.Format("filename[^;=\n]*=((['\"]).*?{0}|[^;\n]*)", Regex.Escape("2"));
            var omitPattern = "filename[^;\n=]*=(([^'\"])*'')?"; 
            var properFormat = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(cdHeader));
            properFormat = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(properFormat);
            properFormat = properFormat.Replace("\"", "");
            
            var matches = Regex.Matches(properFormat, pattern);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                var filename = matches.Cast<Match>().Last().Value;
                filename = Regex.Replace(filename, omitPattern, "");
                var temp = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(filename);
                return temp.ReplaceInvalidChars();
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
        {
            var locUri = new Uri(location);
            var first = Path.GetFileName(locUri.LocalPath);
            if (first.IsCorrectFilename())
            {
                return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(first);
            }
            else
            {
                first = Path.GetFileName(locUri.AbsolutePath);
                return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(first.ReplaceInvalidChars());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var first = Path.GetFileName(resp.ResponseUri.LocalPath);
            if (first.IsCorrectFilename())
            {
                return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(first);
            }
            else
            {
                first = Path.GetFileName(resp.ResponseUri.AbsolutePath);
                return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(first.ReplaceInvalidChars());
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool HasExtension(this string filename)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(filename));
    }
    public static bool HasInvalidChar(this string filename)
    {
        return Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Any(x => filename.Contains(x));
    }
    public static string ReplaceInvalidChars(this string filename)
    {
        foreach (var c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
        {
            filename = filename.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
        }
        return filename;
    }
    public static bool IsCorrectFilename(this string filename)
    {
        return filename.HasExtension() && !filename.HasInvalidChar();
    }

}
```

Comment: This only suits a particular set of URL formats. If that's fine for you, that's fine, but it won't work for URLs like I commented on your question, like `https://example.com/download?id=5`. Your handling of the location header also isn't correct, this indicates a redirect which you should follow. The target location may include a content-disposition header containing a filename when requested.

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster. The Content-Disposition parsed in first conditional case and isn't it the header that we have after all redirections completed? I think no need a second parsing for location.
What should be the filename for your example url?

Comment: In your example url, probably the file is an html page and we can get download.html. If there is another file other than html, Content-Disposition header must be exists, either we cannot get the correct filename from the url.

Comment: If you follow all redirects, the final response won't have a Location header, so that's code that will never be hit. _"What should be the filename for your example url?"_ - that is exactly my point, **there is none**. A browser will generate a name bases on the URL and Content-Type response header, so it might become something like `download_5.pdf`, but this will differ per browser. If my example URL returns a file, it doesn't have to have a Content-Disposition header. It can just send a Content-Type and be done. So while this code may work for your scenario, it won't for everyone.

Comment: @CodeCaster So to fix the issues you told i understand that we need to check CD header for location secondly and plus if there is no suitable filename at the end we should add extension according to the content type getting a filename in the url. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Lastly I have to ask what should i do if Content-Type has multiple matching extension? Does choosing randomly one of them cause a problem?

Answer (score -2):

If you do not have permission for the folder/file you will get an exception and return nothing.  You have to use code like below to continue after an exception occurs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);
            
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
             

                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does a bunch of code that writes an XML file with a local directory structure help with parsing filenames from URLs? There are no filesystems or folders in the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster : TheOP is using Path.GetFileName(response.ResponseUri.OriginalString);

Comment: Again, how does a bunch of filesystem reading and XML writing code help with their problem? They are using `Path.GetFileName()` to parse strings, not to access the filesystem.

Comment: @CodeCoaster: The XML is just an example of output and not required.  You may not be able to fix the problem when you do not have permission to read 1 folder when you have 1000 folders.  But you want to be able to read the 999 folders that you do have permission.  The OPs code will fail if one folder or file has an access issue.  My code will return the 999 folders that do not have an access issue.

Comment: @jdwhee yes, it's fantastic code, perhaps the best folder reading code ever, but the question is not about reading folders or permissions.

Comment: The OP said : "get the filename from a url working without any exception" .  How can the application work when the OP is getting Read Access Exceptions?

Comment: @CoadeCoaster: Now can you remove the negative points you gave me?

Comment: @jdwang oh, no, sorry, that would be impossible. While catching exceptions generally is a great way to make sure no uncaught exceptions are thrown, it is not the solution in this case.

Comment: @CodeCoaster :Then what is the solution?  All you have done is made comments about my code with no solution.

Comment: @jdwhat and I don't do that to annoy you; I am certain that your code does not help with their problem. I have asked the OP for examples. The point is that the data returned from a request to an endpoint like `https://example.com/foo?bar=baz` doesn't necessarily have a filename associated with it. A solution would be to look at the content-type response header and the path of the URI, and determine a filename from that, like `foo.xml`, when the content-type indicates an XML response.